# Tensorflow - The prediction from Neural Network usually goes for all-0s in classification

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I'm new to Deep Learning and currently, I work with the Classification Problem. I've implemented it with the last Fully-Connected Layer & Activation as following Tensorflow:

```
              predictions = tf.layers.dense(attention_layer_output, nb_classes, name="Output_Layer")
              predictions = tf.reduce_sum(predictions, axis = 0)

              targets_raw_ = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions)

              targets_ = tf.round(targets_raw_)

              cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = self._targets, logits = predictions)

              is_correct = tf.equal(targets_, self._targets)

              self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct, tf.float32))

              tf.summary.scalar('Accuracy', self.accuracy)
              adam_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self._learning_rate)
              self.optimizer = adam_opt.minimize(cross_entropy)
```

I've tested with the first 30 epochs, and it's almost overfitting with one of these classes. When I tried to debug what happened in the above code by `tf.Print`, I've found that the prediction is usually [0 0 0 0 0 0] in case **nb_classes = 6**.

So, the accuracy of training usually goes around 83,33%, which means 5/6 class is correct.

Do I have to do anything else with the above code or I still have to wait for training with more epoch?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "almost overfitting with one of these classes".

Comment: @MaximVolgin When I do validation, it's almost (95%) predicted for only 1 class then :D

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your description is that you have imbalanced training set, i.e. not all classes are represented equally. In that case, accuracy is not a good metric because if one of the classes appears most often and the model predicts this class *always*, accuracy is still good despite the fact that model is useless. Have a look at AUC instead.

Comment: There are 6 class. 5 of them have 100  and the rest has 85 items.